# How to load pins just around your current location and load more as you zoom out in Xamarin.Forms.Maps

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.maps

I’m trying to show pins on the map but only the ones that can fit the screen around your current location depending on the zoom level I’ve set on when the map appears, because I have 10’s of pins and when I open the map it loads every pin and takes a long time to load.

Any idea on how to do it ?

**Method to load pins:**

```
    async Task ExecuteLoadPinsCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Map.Pins.Clear();
            Map.MapElements.Clear();
            Map.CustomPins.Clear();
            var contents = await placeRepository.GetAllPlacesWithoutRelatedDataAsync();

            if (contents == null || contents.Count < 1)
            {
                await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No places found", "No places have been found for that category, please try again later", "Ok");
                await ExecuteLoadPinsCommand();
            }

            if (contents != null)
            {
                places.Clear();
                var customPins = this.Map.CustomPins;
                places = contents;
                foreach (var item in places)
                {
                    CustomPin devicePin = new CustomPin
                    {
                        Type = PinType.Place,
                        PlaceId = item.PlaceId.ToString(),
                        Position = new Position(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
                        Label = $"{item.Name}",
                        Address = $"{item.Name}"
                    };

                    Map.CustomPins.Add(devicePin);
                    Map.Pins.Add(devicePin);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

**CustomMapRenderer:**

```
    protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
    {
        CustomPin pin = (CustomPin)pin;
        var thePlace = Task.Run(async () => await placeRepository.GetPlaceByIdWithMoodAndEventsAsync(Guid.Parse(pin.PlaceId)));
        var place = thePlace.ConfigureAwait(true)
                            .GetAwaiter()
                            .GetResult();

        var marker = new MarkerOptions();

        marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(place.Position.Latitude, place.Position.Longitude));
        if (place.Category == "" && place.SomethingCount == 0)
        {
            marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.icon));
        }
        //else if ...

        return marker;

    }
```

Comment: When I had two pins it was like 3 seconds loading and with just close to 20 pins it is like 10 seconds

Comment: I do have a `LoadPins()` inside the `OnAppearing()` so it's pretty much everytime, I'm posting it

Comment: It goes pretty fast when it's only one pin, pretty much less than a second

Comment: I also have `CreateMarker()` method in the `CustomMapRenderer` that creates the marker depending on the data being fed to the list of place, it pretty much does a `GetList()` request per Marker, I think it might be this but I don't know how to do it any other way, let me post what it looks like

Comment: you need to determine what is making it slow.  Is it your code to load the data?  Or the map code that draws the data?  My bet would be that it's your code, not the map.

Comment: So, do you think the problem is more the custom code that does a `GetPlaceByIdWithMoodAndEventsAsync` everytime it needs to load a pin, and in this case should I just create a list of `Place` and pick from it ( if you guys know how the CreateMarker method works btw please let me know, I don't know if it's used like a foreach loop or if I should create a foreach loop in there ) or the map that loads without the pins ?

Comment: What Jason and I are saying is: **test** what takes the time. I've added to my answer. When you can report the times for those 2 tests, then its possible to advise you. And to be very clear: I am not asking how long it takes when there are no pins, or only one pin. I'm asking you to do a careful test to determine which part of the code is taking the time.

Comment: So it seems that I solved the problem by taking `ExecuteLoadPinsCommand()` off of `OnAppearing` which now doesn't load everytime but sometimes and because of it, the app is now usable, but I still don't know how to improve the loading speed, I tried a couple things besides the post you did for now and nothing really gave me the feeling of a faster load besides loading less, I'll add the rest of my Places and will come back to see if it gets worse past a certain number of pins and I think the loading improvement will be more visible, I haven't tried `ItemsSource`, is it faster ?

Comment: I don't have anything more to say, unless you perform the specific tests I suggest, and report performances. Otherwise, its all just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

A major part of programming is learning to debug well.

When facing a performance problem, it is important to isolate the time delay to the smallest bit of code that you can.

Here's the thought process I would go through:

- YOUR OBSERVATION: When there is one pin, it takes less than a second. When there are 20 pins, it takes maybe 10 seconds. (9 second difference.)
- YOUR HYPOTHESIS (Given the question you posted): Maybe adding 20 pins to map takes much or most of the 9 seconds.
- TESTS: How can we test EXACTLY the code that "adds pins to map"?
  A: "Divide and conquer":
  **Let all the other code run 20 times. That is, have 20 pins as data. BUT suppress the code that adds those pins.**

Test #1: Have 20 pins returned by GetAllPlacesWithoutRelatedDataAsync. So all that work is done 20 times.
Comment out JUST the code that ADDS the pins. Make this change:

```
//Map.CustomPins.Add(devicePin);
//Map.Pins.Add(devicePin);
```

Result #1: _____ seconds

Its possible that having NO pins allows the map to skip loading some pin-related code. Lets find out how quick it is when we only ADD ONE of the 20 pins.

Test #2: **Have 20 pins in the data. BUT only ADD one of them.** Make this ONE-LINE change:

```
            foreach (var item in places)
            {
                CustomPin devicePin = new CustomPin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    PlaceId = item.PlaceId.ToString(),
                    Position = new Position(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
                    Label = $"{item.Name}",
                    Address = $"{item.Name}"
                };

                Map.CustomPins.Add(devicePin);
                Map.Pins.Add(devicePin);
                break;   // <--- ADD THIS LINE.
            }
```

Result #2: _____ seconds

(Test #2 is what I was trying to ask you to do, in one of my comments on the question. I've deleted those comments.)

Now we have enough information to determine how much of the ~9 extra seconds are due to going through that foreach loop 20 times, to ADD 20 pins.

This will determine whether there is any point in trying to speed up the ADDS, or whether there is a problem elsewhere.

---

If most time is spent elsewhere, then you need to **add the suspect code to the question**. Then do similar tests there. Until you can report exactly what code takes most of the time.

---

IF 20x `map.Pins.Add(..)` takes a significant amount of time, THEN here are two techniques, either of which should be faster, imho.

FASTER ADD #1:

> [Use `Map.ItemsSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins#display-a-pin-collection).

FASTER ADD #2:

> Create the map WITH its pins, BEFORE displaying it.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace XFSOAnswers
{
    // Based on https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/WorkingWithMaps/WorkingWithMaps/WorkingWithMaps/PinPageCode.cs
    public class PinPageCode : ContentPage
    {
        public PinPageCode()
        {
            Title = "Pins demo";

            Position position = new Position(36.9628066, -122.0194722);
            MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(position, 0.01, 0.01);

            Map map = new Map(mapSpan);

            Pin pin = new Pin
            {
                Label = "Santa Cruz",
                Address = "The city with a boardwalk",
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = position
            };
            map.Pins.Add(pin);
            // ... more pins.

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(10),
                Children =
                {
                    map
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```